# Laravel: wherePivot or where clause on collection on many to many relation table not working?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have a many to many relationship between roles and permissions tables. I am trying to get all the roles and permission where pivot.is_deleted = 0. But the where clause doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

This, I tried on my roles model:

```
public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class,'permission_role','role_id','permission_id')->wherePivot('is_deleted', '=', 0);
    }
```

I have done the same in my permissions model.

This is what I have tried in my controller:

```
$roles = Role::all();
dd($roles); //gives all data without filtering.

$roles= Role::where('is_deleted',0)->whereHas('permissions', function($query){
    $query->where('permissions.pivot.is_deleted', 0);
})->get();
```

Comment: `permissions.pivot.is_deleted` is not a valid column, it would be `permission_role.is_deleted`. But you don't have to specify the `WHERE` clause twice: `$roles = Role::where('is_deleted', 0)->has('permissions')->get();`